# Optional belongs_to relationship in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm migrating an application over to ROR from PHP that defines an object, let's call it a Document that can be created by a User who is either a registered user of the application, or an anonymous user who only gives their email address (in this case without an associated User account). There is no requirement for a visitor to create a User account, but they should still have the ability to create a Document.

In my model, I am first led to create the Document model that references the user with a belongs_to association. This however is not always the case. In pure SQL and PHP this is not hard, although it comes with it's own challenges, but I would like to model this in the "purest" Ruby/Rails way.

If a visitor does not have an associated User, their email address will be stored directly against the Document object.

To start the discussion, here are the snippets for each model.

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
end

# document.rb
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :email_address

  belongs_to :user
end
```

My goal is to be able to retrieve all user documents using the standard dot notation:

```
user.documents
```

And to also check for the reverse relationship to see if the document belongs to a User or if it contains an email address.

```
if document.user.nil? ...

if document.email_address.nil? ...
```

I have read up on the has_one relationship but am not sure if this is the right path to go down.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have more or less answered yourself; the code you have should work just fine for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, I'll go forward with what I have and update here if I run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider making the User class more flexible so it supports anonymous users and only stores the email address.

It might make your code a bit cleaner.

Comment: I fear this approach would complicate the User model validation since the required fields are defined in the model definition. I guess I failed to mention that part, sorry. Thanks for the suggestion though!